# iPad wifi greyed out; Can't reset

Tags: ipad, icloud, wifi

So my iPad's (running iOS 9.3.5) WiFi toggle of set to off and greyed out. I have not encountered such a problem on any iOS device before.

To make matters worse, when I try to reset the iPad to solve this problem, I am asked to enter my iCloud password, but when I do, I get an error saying the Id server could not be contacted (which obviously will happen since my WiFi is not working.)

So is this a catch-22 that cannot be solved?

Comment: Try resetting Network settings on your iPad and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Done that already

Comment: Try restoring your iPad through iTunes.

Comment: Inadvertent Airplane mode?